# Data cleaning in Pandas data frame based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I need help in cleaning data that appears for short period of time using Pandas.

"When data appear for short duration < 5mins, I want to remove those data from data frame, otherwise keep them in the data frame." ***In figure 1***, in both yellow and blue colour part, there are label data for more than 5mins. Therefore, I want to keep those data in data frame. However, in green colour part, there are label data for 1min, which is less than 5mins. So, I want to remove them from data frame. **Therefore, How can I code that data cleaning requirement in Python using Pandas library package?**

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii718.jpg)

Comment: did you try something? can you add a [mre]? Currently the question consists of multiple questions - can you narrow this down to a specific problem? Note that you can make and edit; the question can then be re-opened.

Comment: Two major things are wrong with your question: data (we can cp[y/paste for testing)  is missing and your python code (to see and run) on what you've tried. Removing fig2 and 3 cannot be judged, regardless of the "focus" feedback from the close-vote due to the two major flaws in the question. [mcve]. End of Review.